# Ошибка MySqlConnection: "void cannot be as argument type"

Tags: mysql, winforms, c++-cli

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой MySqlConnection.

> Ошибка: error C2860: 'void' cannot be an argument type, except for
>   '(void)'

Ошибка указывает на строку `MySqlConnection^ mysqlConnection = gcnew MySqlConnection(connectionStr);`

Почему то когда вставляю этот код в новый проект, тогда все работает. А в моем почему то нет.
В чем может быть ошибка?

```
void WriteEvent(String^ type, String^ component, String^ info) {
            try {
                String^ connectionStr = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
                String^ commandStr = "INSERT INTO `machine_ab5cd`.`machine_ab5cd` (`TIMESTAMP`) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
                MySqlConnection^ mysqlConnection = gcnew MySqlConnection(connectionStr);
                MySqlCommand^ mysqlCommand = gcnew MySqlCommand(commandStr, mysqlConnection);
                MySqlDataReader^ mysqlDataReader;
                mysqlConnection->Open();
                mysqlDataReader = mysqlCommand->ExecuteReader();
            } catch(Exception^ ex) {
                MessageBox::Show(ex->ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Поробуйте так `gcnew MySqlConnection("...");`

Comment: Если код работает сам по себе, значит, его окружение содержит ошибки. Может, где-то метод не закрыли, в итоге компилятор видит задвоенную переменную, скажем, либо вообще ругается на void в объявлении функции, потому что уровень видимости не тот. Компилятор C++ вообще характеризовался невменяемостью выдаваемого списка ошибок после первой, поскольку пропускал строку с ошибкой при последующем анализе.

Comment: Но если я удаляю этот код из программы, то она компилируется. Наверно этот код не работает только с этой программой.